# type parameter t has incompatible upper bounds view and gridview

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

Estoy teniendo un problema extraño, en mi clase:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
```

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridView extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private GridView gridView;
private GridAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_cuidados);

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("Paola");
    arrayList.add("Rodrigo");
    arrayList.add("Hernan");
    arrayList.add("Stefi");
    arrayList.add("Pablo");

    gridView = findViewById(R.id.gvElegir);
    adapter = new GridAdapter(this,arrayList);
}
```

}

me marca en rojo esta línea y me da el error del título:

> gridView = findViewById(R.id.gvElegir);

A alguien le pasó algo similar? Cómo lo solucionaron?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: cual es el id de tu GridView (en el xml)?

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar, tenia un listview creado funcionando y lo modifique por un gridview para poder ver la informacion como yo queria. Muchas gracias!